# How can I allow scp to a user whose login shell is a restricted shell via rbash

Tags: bash, scp, restricted-shell

Hi I have a login shell via /bin/rbash
However i cannot scp to the home directory.
Is there anyway to solve this?

```
scp /tmp/x user@ip:/home/ubuntu/x
```

how to make above work when user always gets a restricted shell on login

Comment: Use SFTP, instead of SCP. Or if you like the commandline interface of `scp`, use up-to-date version of OpenSSH, in which `scp` uses SFTP. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/22764511/850848

Comment: @MartinPrikryl, if users are configured with rbash as their shell, chances are the sftp subsystem is not enabled either as that would allow circumventing some of the restrictions. In any case, restricted shells are very weak security measures so there's probably  a way to work around it, but that would likely go against the policies put in place by the administrators

Comment: If your shell is a restricted shell, you have an account where actions are restricted. You should check the terms of use for what is acceptable or contact the system administrators.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because OP appears to be trying to bypass local security policy. If that is a constraint he/she should speak his local IT support.

Answer (score 0):

You may find it convenient to configure a separate account, within same group, for remote scp access.
And then in the file system use chmod to allow group permission for the required access.